# Условный оператор в sql выходит с ошибкой

Tags: sql

Почему этот запрос выдаёт ошибку?

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `time` = '2016-09-05 18:07:00.000000' AND `author` = 'user') = 0) THEN
    UPDATE `messages` SET `text`='test', `author`='user', `time`='2016-09-05 18:07:00.000000', `ticket`='111';
END IF;
```

#1064 ошибка в первой строке. Нужно вставить строку в таблицу, если с определёнными колонками не найдены такие же строки (id может не совпасть, всё остальное строго). (Пробую выполнять пока в phpmyadmin.) Протестировал запрос в самом if без этой конструкции. Он выполняется, но как только пытаюсь условие поставить - выходит ошибка. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие инструкции как IF можно применять только внутри хранимых процедур. К языку запросов SQL они никакого отношения не имеют.

Ваш запрос можно переписать так:

```
UPDATE `messages`
   SET `text`='test', `author`='user', `time`='2016-09-05 18:07:00.000000', `ticket`='111'
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM `messages`
     WHERE `time` = '2016-09-05 18:07:00.000000' AND `author` = 'user'
 )
```

Так же обратите внимание, что в случае если условие выполнится, т.е. не будет найдено ни одной записи удовлетворяющей условию, данный update *поменяет значение во всех строках* таблицы, так как никаких условий указывающих на то, какие строки должны быть изменены нет.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказанное направление решения. В вопросе перепутал UPDATE с INSERT. Для тех, кто столкнётся с этим вопросом, оставлю своё решение задачи.    `INSERT INTO messages (text, author, time, ticket)
 SELECT 'test' AS text, 'user' AS author, '2016-09-05 18:07:00.000000' AS time, '111' AS ticket FROM messages
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE text='test' AND author='user' AND time='2016-09-05 18:07:00.000000' AND ticket='111')
LIMIT 1`